# How to resolve multiple controller error when using ASP.NET sitemap provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using ASP.NET MVC3 and [ASP.NET MVC Sitemap Provider](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/).

I have a controller named Application.  I also have an area called Administration.  In the administration area I also have a controller called Application.

The first application controller is for normal website users.  The other application controller is intended for administrators.

I would like my URLs to display as such:

```
/Application/1001/Notes
/Administration/Application/1001/Notes
```

The route registration that I have for the 2 above URLs are as such:

```
Routes.MapRoute("ApplicationNote",
     "{controller}/{applicationId}/Notes",
     new { controller = "Application", action = "Notes" },
     new { applicationId = @"\d+" },
     new[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" });

Routes.MapRoute("AdminApplicationNote",
     "{area}/{controller}/{applicationId}/Notes",
     new { area = "Administration", controller = "Application", action = "Notes" },
     new { applicationId = @"\d+" },
     new[] { "MyProject.Web.Areas.Administration.Controllers" });
```

When I run my application and go to any of the action methods in the application controller then I get an error here:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
```

And the error is:

```
Found multiple controllers:Application
```

Here is a partial view of my sitemap configuration:

```
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" area="" controller="Home" action="About" />

 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Applications" area="" controller="Application" action="Index" key="ApplicationIndex">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Create Application" area="" controller="Application" action="Create" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Applications List" controller="Application" area="" action="List" />
 </mvcSiteMapNode>

 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Administration Dashboard" area="Administration" controller="Dashboard" action="Index">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Users Dashboard" area="Administration" controller="User" action="List" />
 </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

How would I resolve this?  if I remove the route called AdminApplicationNote the other application URLs display correctly.  But then I can get the 2nd area route to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Provider?

Routes look ok in general. I had issues like this before (in a more complex scenario) and SiteMap used namespace resolution (which should work as your namespaces for routes suggest controllers are different).

I'd  suggest that you get the code for [MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultControllerTypeResolver](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/DefaultControllerTypeResolver.cs) from github. Think it is throwing exception at line 285 relating to using the namespace to locate controller. Use source to implement your own version (could of course just step into their code if you have got it) and use then use your version break point and step in and identify why it is claiming their are duplicates.  You will need to register your implementation in the Web.config. e.g. something like

```
controllerTypeResolver="MyProject.Web.YourControllerTypeResolver, MyProject"
```

I have had to do that when creating a Multi-Tenant application where tenants had different controllers and I had to provide alternative resolution strategy.

Also in general do you need the empty Area (I never do that). Also in general do you need to specify the controller in the child nodes etc as if you don't I'm sure it uses the parent nodes.

---Update--

I think it may have been a bug. Have a look here https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/78

Should be fixed in 3.3.4.0